# statsmodels grangercausalitytests—how to interpret OLS estimation results?

Tags: time-series, granger-causality

[Here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.grangercausalitytests.html) is the documentation for the test of granger non causality. They return OLS estimates for the restricted and unrestricted model. However, on the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality) description of granger causality they describe fitting an autoregression model so I'm unsure on how I'm supposed to use the linear regression results discussed on time series data.